# Implement update in Entity Manager and call it using a JSF Managed Bean

Tags: database, netbeans, javabeans, entitymanager

I am using netbeans 7.2.1 with jdk version 6 and primefaces 3.4.1. I have created a database, and created Entities from the database and then JSF pages from the entities.

I now have a jsf managed bean which is creating a mindmap for the program by extracting the users from the database and connecting them according to whether or not their username is contained in a certain string.

There is a double click facility in mindmap which I want to use to update the database, but for some reason it isn't working. I don't get an error message, just nothing changes.

This is what I've tried to use to implement the update function:

```
package jpa.session;

import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.NoResultException;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import jpa.entities.Enginetable;


@Stateless
public class EnginetableFacade extends AbstractFacade<Enginetable> {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "Networks0.75PU")
    private EntityManager em;


    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

    public EnginetableFacade() {
        super(Enginetable.class);
    }        

    public Enginetable setUserdetails( Enginetable user ) {
        try 
        {        
            return em.merge(user); 
        } 

        catch (NoResultException nre) 
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

But it doesn't work. Note that I have no problem accessing the database but haven't included the code here.

This is the relevant method:

```
    public void onNodeDblselect(SelectEvent event) {
        this.user.setConnections( this.user.getConnections() + "-" + this.selectedNode.getLabel() );
        this.selectedNode = (MindmapNode) event.getObject();
        this.ejbFacade.setUserdetails( this.user );
    }
```

This is the call from the xhtml

```
    <p:mindmap value="#{mmBean.root}" style="width:100%;height:600px">
        <p:ajax event="dblselect" listener="#{mmBean.onNodeDblselect}" update="output" />
    </p:mindmap>
```

Please, any advice would be fantastic.

This is the full code for the bean:

```
package jsf;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.persistence.Version;
import jpa.entities.Enginetable;
import jpa.session.EnginetableFacade;
import org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent;
import org.primefaces.model.mindmap.DefaultMindmapNode;
import org.primefaces.model.mindmap.MindmapNode;

/**
 *
 * @author AOL
 */
@Named(value = "mmBean")
@ViewScoped
public class mmBean implements Serializable{

    @EJB
    private jpa.session.EnginetableFacade ejbFacade;
    private MindmapNode root;

    private MindmapNode selectedNode;

    PreparedStatement pst = null;

    private List<Enginetable> elements;
    private List<Enginetable> filteredElements;
    private List<Enginetable> userlist;


    private Enginetable selectedElement;
    private Enginetable[] selectedElements; 



    private Enginetable current;

    private Enginetable nodeentity = new Enginetable();
    private Enginetable user = new Enginetable();
    private String connections;
    private String[] strConnections;
    private String[] userConn;
    private List<String> indirectConn = new ArrayList<String>();
    private String[]  iConn;

    private Object rootlabel;

    //ADDED BY AODHÁN
    Connection con = null;
    Statement st = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:8080/networkdb";
    String theuser = "Aodhan";
    String password = "Cavelcade1988";


    /**
     * Creates a new instance of MmBean
     */
    public mmBean() {
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

        this.userlist = this.getFullList();
        Enginetable entity;

        //remoteuser=null;

        // filteredElements = new ArrayList<Enginetable>();
        this.user = this.userlist.get(0);

        this.userConn = this.user.getConnections().split("-");

        root = new DefaultMindmapNode(user.getStartnode(), "Google", "006666", false);


        this.rootlabel = this.root.getLabel();
        for( int i = 0 ; i < this.userlist.size() ; i++){

                    entity = this.userlist.get(i);

                    if ( !rootlabel.equals(entity.getStartnode() ) && Arrays.asList(this.userConn).contains( entity.getStartnode() ) ) {
                        connections = entity.getConnections();
                        iConn = connections.split("-");
                        boolean addAll;
                        addAll = this.indirectConn.addAll(Arrays.asList(iConn));
                    }

        }

        for( int i = 0 ; i < this.userlist.size() ; i++){

                    entity = this.userlist.get(i);

                    if ( !rootlabel.equals(entity.getStartnode() ) ) {


                if ( Arrays.asList(this.userConn).contains( entity.getStartnode() ) )  { 

                                root.addNode(new DefaultMindmapNode(entity.getStartnode() , "Malicious Software: ", "33FF00"));

                            } 



                                else if ( !Arrays.asList(this.userConn).contains( entity.getStartnode() ) && this.indirectConn.contains( entity.getStartnode() ) ){

                                    root.addNode(new DefaultMindmapNode(entity.getStartnode() , "Malicious Software: ", "00FFFF"));

                                } 


                else{

                                    root.addNode(new DefaultMindmapNode( entity.getStartnode() , "Malicious Software: ", "CC0000"));

                }

            }

        }

    }

    public MindmapNode getRoot() {
        return root;
    }

    public MindmapNode getSelectedNode() {
        return selectedNode;
    }
    public void setSelectedNode(MindmapNode selectedNode) {
        this.selectedNode = selectedNode;
    }

    public void onNodeSelect(SelectEvent event) {
        MindmapNode node = (MindmapNode) event.getObject();


            for( int i = 0 ; i < this.userlist.size() ; i++){
                    Enginetable entity;
                    Object label = node.getLabel();

                    entity = userlist.get(i);
                    if ( entity.getStartnode() == label ){
                        this.nodeentity = entity;
                    }

            }
    //load children of select node and add via node.addNode(childNode);
    //populate if not already loaded
            if(node.getChildren().isEmpty()) {
               this.setChildNodes( node ); 
            }
        }


    public void onNodeDblselect(SelectEvent event) {
        this.user.setConnections( this.user.getConnections() + "-" + this.selectedNode.getLabel() );
        this.selectedNode = (MindmapNode) event.getObject();
        this.ejbFacade.setUserdetails( this.user );
    }

    public void setUserlist(List<Enginetable> elements) {
        this.userlist = elements;
    }

    public List<Enginetable> getUserlist() {
        return this.userlist;
    }

    public void setUser(Enginetable element) {
        this.user = element;
    }

    public Enginetable getUser() {
        return this.user;
    }

    public void setFilteredElements(List<Enginetable> filteredElements) {
        //this.filteredElements = filteredElements;
        this.elements=filteredElements;
    }

    public List<Enginetable> getFilteredElements() {
        return filteredElements;
    }

    public void setSelectedElements(Enginetable[] selectedElements) {
        this.selectedElements = selectedElements;
    }

    public Enginetable[] getSelectedElements() {
        return selectedElements;
    }

    public void setSelectedElement(Enginetable selectedElement) {
        this.selectedElement = selectedElement;
    }

    public Enginetable getSelectedElement() {
        return selectedElement;
    }

    private EnginetableFacade getFacade() {
        return ejbFacade;
    }  

    // ADDED BY AODHÁN

    public List<Enginetable> getListByUsername(String user){
       return this.ejbFacade.getEnginetableByUsername(user);
    } 

    public List<Enginetable> getListByUserID( int id ){
       return this.ejbFacade.getEnginetableByUserid(id);
    } 

    public List<Enginetable> getFullList(){
       return this.ejbFacade.getFullEnginetable();
    } 

    public Enginetable setUserdetails( Enginetable user ){
       return this.ejbFacade.setUserdetails( user );
    } 

    public void setChildNodes( MindmapNode node ){

        Object label = node.getLabel();
        this.rootlabel = this.root.getLabel();
        this.strConnections = nodeentity.getConnections().split("-");

        for( int i = 0 ; i < this.userlist.size() ; i++){

            Enginetable entity;

            entity = this.userlist.get(i);


            if ( !label.equals(entity.getStartnode() ) && !this.rootlabel.equals( entity.getStartnode() ) ) {

                if ( Arrays.asList(this.userConn).contains( entity.getStartnode() ) && !Arrays.asList(this.strConnections).contains( entity.getStartnode() ) ){

                    node.addNode(new DefaultMindmapNode(entity.getStartnode() , "Malicious Software: ", "33FF00"));

                }   

                else if ( !Arrays.asList(this.userConn).contains( entity.getStartnode() ) && this.indirectConn.contains( entity.getStartnode() ) ){

                    node.addNode(new DefaultMindmapNode(entity.getStartnode() , "Malicious Software: ", "00FFFF"));

                } 

                else if ( Arrays.asList(this.userConn).contains( entity.getStartnode() ) && Arrays.asList(this.strConnections).contains( entity.getStartnode() ) ){

                    node.addNode(new DefaultMindmapNode(entity.getStartnode() , "Malicious Software: ", "0066FF"));

                }

        else if ( !Arrays.asList(this.userConn).contains( entity.getStartnode() ) && Arrays.asList(this.strConnections).contains( entity.getStartnode() ) ){

                    node.addNode(new DefaultMindmapNode(entity.getStartnode() , "Malicious Software: ", "FFCC00"));

                } 

                else if ( !Arrays.asList(this.userConn).contains( entity.getStartnode() ) && !Arrays.asList(this.strConnections).contains( entity.getStartnode() ) ){

                    node.addNode(new DefaultMindmapNode(entity.getStartnode() , "Malicious Software: ", "CC0000"));

                } 

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised what the problem was, and it was twofold, it seems.

```
  public void onNodeDblselect(SelectEvent event) {
        this.user.setConnections( this.user.getConnections() + "-" + this.selectedNode.getLabel() );
        this.selectedNode = (MindmapNode) event.getObject();
        this.ejbFacade.setUserdetails( this.user );
    }
```

I was calling this.selectedNode before it was defined, here.

```
public Enginetable setUserdetails( Enginetable user ) {
    try 
    {        
        return em.merge(user); 
    }  

    catch (NoResultException nre) 
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

It doesn't like this return statement, so I broke it up.

```
public Enginetable setUserdetails( Enginetable user ) {
    try 
    {        
        em.merge(user); 
        em.flush();
        return user;
    } 

    catch (NoResultException nre) 
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I will have to make the page update, but that is a html problem.